# DRF - how to pass a value to a serializer, omitting user's request body

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Imagine we have such a simple model:

```py
class Tag(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.TextField()
```

and a serializer for it:

```py
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=False,
        write_only=True,
        queryset=User.objects.all(),
    )
    title = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ("owner", "title")
        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=Tag.objects.all(),
                fields=["owner", "title"],
                message="",
            )
        ]
```

The current (simplified) view:

```py
class TagCreateView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = TagSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def create(self, request: Request, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Response:
        data = request.data
        data["owner"] = self.request.user.pk
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    def post(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Response:
        return self.create(*args, **kwargs)
```

Well, the task sounds quite simple: how to pass the `owner` instance (or it's primarykey) from a view, but to keep the field invisible for a user? I mean, it hasn't be rendered by drf-yasg, and user shouldn't know about it.

Is there only a single way - to pass the value via context, and then rewrite serializer's validate (instead of using UniqueTogetherValidator) & update & create methods to support it?

I hope you know better approaches.

Comment: Please add your view to the question.

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem. Please describe what you expect from a `GET` and `POST` request, respectively.

Comment: The problem is only with building a Serializer from a raw json (that is, with POST requests only). I wanna hide the "owner" field from the API Client's interface, and to init it with request.user instead.

Comment: you're probably looking for `get_serializer_context`?

Comment: Nope, I'm looking for any alternative variant

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the [`HiddenField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#hiddenfield):

> A field class that does not take a value based on user input, but instead takes its value from a default value or callable.

```py
owner = serializers.HiddenField(default=get_user_id)
```

[`default`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#default) can be a callable as can be seen in this example from the docs:

```
# Source: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#default
class CurrentUserDefault:
    """
    May be applied as a `default=...` value on a serializer field.
    Returns the current user.
    """
    requires_context = True

    def __call__(self, serializer_field):
        return serializer_field.context['request'].user
```